# Send message from Android to Controller by OTG

Tags: java, android, usb-otg, android-usb

I'm trying to make a communication between Android and a controller. I would like to ask how to configure the message, since I have seen different ways, but I can not know why each way.
I want to send the message from Android to the controller, in 32 bytes. I have this code:

```
private void sendData(){

    int baudRate = 115200;
    byte stopBitsByte = 1;
    byte parityBitesByte = 0;
    byte dataBits = 32;
    byte[] msg = {
            (byte) (baudRate & 0xff),
            (byte) ((baudRate >> 8) & 0xff),
            (byte) ((baudRate >> 16) & 0xff),
            (byte) ((baudRate >> 24) & 0xff),
            stopBitsByte,
            parityBitesByte,
            (byte) dataBits
    };

    deviceConnection.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_CLASS | 0x01, 0x20, 0, 0, msg, msg.length,5000);
    deviceConnection.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_TYPE_CLASS | 0x01, 0x22, 0x1, 0, null, 0, 0);
}
```

Another thing that I have very clear is how a message is received from the controller to Android. For this I have this code:

```
private void receiveData(){

    int bufferMaxLength=epIN.getMaxPacketSize();
    ByteBuffer mBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferMaxLength);
    UsbRequest inRequest = new UsbRequest();
    inRequest.initialize(deviceConnection, epIN);

    while(inRequest.queue(mBuffer, bufferMaxLength) == true) {
        deviceConnection.requestWait();
    }
}
```

PS: Is the first time I use UsbDevice, UsbManager, USBInterface, UsbEndpoint, UsbDeviceConnection, UsbRequest or UsbConstants.

PS2: The codes are provided to send and receive a message from Android Arduino and vice versa.